# SSH to remote server

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, aix

this could be a very easy question, I have read some articles but I cannot fit those articles to my situation:

I have from remote.com server a pair of private and public keys (.ppk) for user 'dummy'.

I am in some Unix server (AIX 7.1) and I want to do:

```
ssh dummy@remote.server with prompt the login
```

We don't know the password they just provided the keys to log in into the server.

What we have to do?

Just in case: We don't have puttygen and We are not allowed to install it, do we have to ask for PEM format keys?

Comment: Add your public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in the remote machine then you can ssh into it by doing ssh dummy@remote.server -i link_to_private_key

Comment: We dont have access to the remote server we just have the pair of keys from the remote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making some assumptions:

- That the people who have given you the public/private key pair have set up the remote server "dummy" account appropriately
- The version of SSH on your local UNIX server is OpenSSH (or something similar)

You need to save the private key you have been given somewhere safe on the filesystem, but this needs to be in the format the local SSH client understands - and for this you will need to run it through 'puttygen'. Does not have to be on the local server, just somewhere to get the right format of key.

```
ssh -i <identity-file> dummy@<servername>
```

should do the trick.